# Help me understand hexadecimal to binary conversion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I understand this up to the last part. How did they figure out the ones and the zeros?

I know how to convert to/from hex/binary to/from decimal but not from hex to binary and vice versa.

Comment: No computations needed, just do a string replace of hex digit to 4 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part is

$$2\times 2^{12}+(2^3+2^2+2^1+1)\times 2^8+(2^3+2^1+1)\times 2^4+(2+1)$$

Expand all to get

$$2^{13}+(2^{11}+2^{10}+2^{9}+2^8)+(2^7+2^5+2^4)+(2^1+2^0)$$

Now we will introduce the missing powers of $2$ with a zero coefficient

$$1\times 2^{13}+\color{green}{0\times 2^{12}}+1\times 2^{11}+1\times 2^{10}+1\times 2^{9}+1\times 2^8+ 1\times 2^7+\\\color{green}{0\times 2^{6}}+1\times 2^5+ 1\times 2^4+\color{green}{0\times 2^3}+\color{green}{0\times 2^2}+1\times 2^1+1\times 2^0$$

It suffices now to read the sequence of $0$ and $1$ coefficients before the powers

$$1\color{green}011111\color{green}011\color{green}{00}11$$

Of course for practical conversion it is easier to have a map between hexadecimal digits and packets of four binary digits, as illustracted in Berci's answer.

$\begin{array}{l|ccl|ccl|ccl|c}
0 & 0000 & \quad & 4 & 0100 & \quad & 8 & 1000 & \quad & C & 1100\\
1 & 0001 & \quad & 5 & 0101 & \quad & 9 & 1001 & \quad & D & 1101\\ 
2 & 0010 & \quad & 6 & 0110 & \quad & A & 1010 & \quad & E & 1110\\
3 & 0011 & \quad & 7 & 0111 & \quad & B & 1011 & \quad & F & 1111\\
\end{array}$

Answer (score 3):

We have $2^4=16$, so hexadecimal to binary is just like the number system of $10000$ to decimal, i.e. one 'digit' in the bigger system is a bunch of $4$ digits in the smaller system.

Where you can see a $2^k$ in the sum, it means that the $(k+1)$th digit is $1$.

$$2FB3_{(16)}\ =\ \underbrace{0010}_2 \, \underbrace{1111}_F\, \underbrace{1011}_B\, \underbrace{0011}_3\,_{(2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

As Berci said, just string replace (left hex, right binary)

- $0 \to 0000$
- $1 \to 0001$
- $2 \to 0010$
- $3 \to 0011$
- $4 \to 0100$
- $5 \to 0101$
- $6 \to 0110$
- $7 \to 0111$
- $8 \to 1000$
- $9 \to 1001$
- $A \to 1010$
- $B \to 1011$
- $C \to 1100$
- $D \to 1101$
- $E \to 1110$
- $F \to 1111$

to replace every hex-"digit" by 4 bits and vice versa. hex to binary is really simple. Octal is similar, but we replace $0-7$ by $3$ bits each.

Answer (score 0):

$16 = 2^4$ and each digit $0,...., F$ can be written as $a*2^3 + b*2^2+ c*2 + d*2^0 = a*8 + b*4 + c*2 + d*1 = abcd_2$ where $a,b,c,d$ are all either $0$ or $1$.

For instance $0 = 0*8 + 0*4 + 0*2 + 0*1$ so $0 \mapsto 0000_2$.

And $C_{16} = 12_{10}= 8+4 = 1*8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 0*1 = 1100_2$.

And so on.

Because the onle digits are $1$ and $0$ we can maybe saving our fingers and typing by just jumping to binary.

Example:

Instead of writing $D= 13_{10} = 8 + 4 + 1 = $

$\color{red}{ 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 = }$

$1101_2$

we can skipp typing out the red stuff.

$0 = 0+0+0+0 = 0000_2$

$1 = 0+0+0+1 = 0001_2$

$2 = 0+0+2+0 = 0010_2$

$3 = 0+0+ 2+1 = 0011_2$

$4 = 0+4+0+0 = 0100_2$.

Etc.

Now when we something like

$F\times 16^2$

And we know that $A = 10 = 8+0+2+0 = 1010_2$

And we know that $16^2 = 2^8 = 100000000_2$

We have  $A\times 16^2 = (8+0+2+0)\times 2^{8} = 8*2^8 + 0*2^8 + 2*2^8 + 0*2^8=$

$1*2^3*2^8 + 0*2^2*2^8 + 1*2^1*2^8 + 0*2^8 =$

$1*2^11 + 0*2^{10} + 1*2^9 + 0*2^8 + 0*2^7 + 0*2^6 + .....=$

$(1010)00000000$.

Again we don't have to type so hard.

$A = 8+2 = 8+0+2+0=2^3 + 0 + 2^1+0 =1010_2$ and we are multiplying $2^8$

so $A\times 2^8 = 2^{11} + 0 + 2^9 + 0$.

Just skip  $A\times 2^8 = (8+0+2+0)\times 2^8 = (1010)\times 2^8 = (1010)00000000$.

So just convert:

$2FB3_{16} = (0+0+2+0)\times 16^3 + (8+4+3+1)\times 16^2 + (8 + 0+2+1)\times 16 + (0+0+2+1)\times 16^0 =$

$(0010)2^{12} + (1111)\times 16^2 + (1011)\times 16 + (0011)\times 16^0=$

$0010111110110011_2$.

It's really just a matter of spacing out the four spaces:

$\underbrace{ 2}_{\times 2^{12}}\underbrace {F}_{\times 2^8}\underbrace {B}_{\times 2^4}\underbrace{ 3}_{\times 2^0} =$

$\underbrace{(0+0+2+0)}_{\times 1000000000000_2}\underbrace {(8+4+2+1)}_{\times 100000000_2}\underbrace {(8+0+2+1)}_{\times 10000_2}\underbrace{(0+0+2+1)}_{\times 1_2} =$

$\underbrace{0010_2}_{\times 1000000000000_2}\underbrace {1111_2}_{\times 100000000_2}\underbrace {1010_2}_{\times 10000_2}\underbrace{0011}_{\times 1_2} =$

${\underbrace{0010}\underbrace {1111}\underbrace {1010}\underbrace{0011}}_2 =$